# Gitlab setup not sending email

Tags: email, azure, smtp, gitlab

I am trying to setup GitLab in windows azure. I followed this blog [Setup GitLab in azure](https://about.gitlab.com/2016/07/13/how-to-setup-a-gitlab-instance-on-microsoft-azure/) and it is working as charm. But I could not configure smtp mail sending through GitLab.

- I have followed this settings [SMTP Setup](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/doc/settings/smtp.md). Tried both Gmail and Zoho, with both ports 465 and 587

I am getting the following error

```
2016-09-21_09:44:28.55626 2016-09-21T09:44:28.556Z 13562 TID-vskyw WARN: {"class":"ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::SidekiqAdapter::JobWrapper","wrapped":"ActionMailer::DeliveryJob","queue":"mailers","args":[{"job_class":"ActionMailer::DeliveryJob","job_id":"6a954ac7-19d6-4b27-b28c-c511f25e6896","queue_name":"mailers","arguments":["DeviseMailer","confirmation_instructions","deliver_now",{"_aj_globalid":"gid://gitlab/User/1"},"tgShkQTx5e1sALoxkkGi",{"to":"<my email here>","_aj_symbol_keys":["to"]}],"locale":"en"}],"retry":true,"jid":"cbd7dc87ce4202265d1a6be7","created_at":1474450319.7324607,"enqueued_at":1474451065.2083879,"error_message":"end of file reached","error_class":"EOFError","failed_at":1474450320.9358478,"retry_count":5,"retried_at":1474451068.5555682}
```

`2016-09-21_09:44:28.55639 2016-09-21T09:44:28.556Z 13562 TID-vskyw WARN: EOFError: end of file reached`

- I tried various combinations for SSL and TLS, but no luck yet!

I am using GitLab `8.11.7`

Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

I tried with GMail smtp and it works fine after allowing access to apps using this [URL](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps). This issue might be due to some Zoho's smtp policy

Answer (score 0):

You should use the new smtp configurations

> If you're installing from source and use SMTP to deliver mail, you will need to add the following line to config/initializers/smtp_settings.rb:
>
> `ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp`

As seen in https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/update/8.10-to-8.11.md#smtp-configuration

A configuration exemple for `smtp_settings.rb` is:

```
if Rails.env.production?
  Rails.application.config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    address: "email.server.com",
    port: 465,
    user_name: "smtp",
    password: "123456",
    domain: "gitlab.company.com",
    authentication: :login,
    enable_starttls_auto: true,
    openssl_verify_mode: 'peer' # See ActionMailer documentation for other possible options
  }
end
```

You can see the sample file doc for configuring SMTP at https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/8-12-stable/config/initializers/smtp_settings.rb.sample#L13?

You can see more configuration options here http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html#class-ActionMailer::Base-label-Configuration+options